# changing html elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have this 24 'dd' and i would like to obtain:
**'dd id="dede0"
'dd id="dede1"**
....    if i use this:

```
var i=0;  
         var dede="dede";  
         var dedos="dede"  
          $('dd').each(function(){

             dede=dede&i;                         
             $('dd').attr("id",dede);
             i++;
             dede=dedos;
          });
```

i change the id of the general 'dd' but, Can i change every specific dd id's???

Thank you very much,

Álvaro

Answer (score 1):

Yo should try

```
  $('dd').each(function(index, el){
     //you could also use el.id                         
     this.id = "dede"+index;
  });
```

when you iterate with [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `this` refers to the current element and you can use the index property to "index" the various id as suggested in the comment

Comment: Is the reason that you are using `i` still instead of `index` just in case the `i` is needed outside of the loop (ie changing to index would have minor side effects)?

Comment: @Chris changing to index would be even better, i was just in a hurry and didn't think of it, i'll update the code

Comment: Cool. I was just curious because you'd explicitly put it in the parameter list which most people don't bother with. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;  
var dede = "dede";  
var dedos = "dede"  

$('dd').each(function() {
    dede = dede + i;                         
    $(this).attr("id", dede);
    i++;
    dede = dedos;
});
```

Comment: You could simply do `this.id = dede` and save a call

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are selecting all the `<dd>` elements in the loop again with `$('dd')`, so every iteration is setting all the `<dd>` IDs. So at the end of the loop all the elements have the same ID with whatever the latest valid of `i` is. To fix this, you can use the current element as denoted by `this` (or `e` as supplied by the jQuery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method).

The most compact solution I can think of is:

```
$('dd').each(function(i, e){                      
  e.id = 'dede' + i;
});​
```